# Remove netdata package from Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, netdata

I'm trying to get rid of `netdata` from my Yocto environment. So I added it to the `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove` variable inside my `<image>.bb` file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "netdata"
```

I also added it to `conf/bblayers.conf` file:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "netdata"
```

Then I removed the output directory (`rm -rf tmp-glibc`) and the `buildhistory/.../netdata` directory and I bitbaked my image again.

Unfortunately the package is still compiled and goes into the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yocto is hard to learn, and I'm still learning it, so I'm not a Yocto expert, and might even be wrong. But I hope I can help you.

1. I think that you don't have to modify your `bblayers.conf` by adding

   ```
   DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "netdata"
   ```
2. Are you sure that the `netdata` package is not needed by any other packages? For example, if inside `recipe-a.bb` you have:

   ```
   RDEPENDS += "recipe-b"
   ```

   Then `recipe-b` is automatically included in the result image.

My advice is: check the `netdata` dependencies with

```
bitbake -g <packagename-or-imagename> -u taskexp
```

Because maybe this is needed from some other package, and you have to remove the other package too in order to see `netdata` removed.

If the package is always there, as a last resort you can also try to clean the entire image with:

```
bitbake -c cleanall <imagename>
```

And then rebuild it with:

```
bitbake <imagename>
```

Source: https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Inspect_DEPENDS